# How to plot ROC-curve in sklearn for LASSO method?

Tags: python, machine-learning, roc, lasso-regression

I want to compare lasso with other classifiers in sklearn. I have a binary outcome vector y. I usually compute a vector probas that contains the predicted probability for each input point to have 1 as a phenotype and then generate a ROC curve fro these 2 vectors. But how to compute this probability for lasso classifier? There is no method predict_proba.

For other classifiers this code works:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cross_validation import LeaveOneOut
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics

#loading a toy dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]

y = iris.target
X, y = X[y != 2], y[y != 2]
classifiers = [

    RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, n_estimators=10, max_features=1),
    LogisticRegression(),
]

classifierNames=[ "Random Forests", "Logistic Regression" ]
for clf in classifiers:
    print (clf)
    loo = LeaveOneOut(len(y))
    probas=[]
    for train, test in loo:

        probas.append ( clf.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])[0][1])


#probas is a vector that contains the probability of getting phenotype 1
#Then we just need to use our auc roc function for plotting.
```

dfphenotypes=pd.DataFrame(y)
    dfpredicted=pd.DataFrame(probas)

```
#probas contains the probability of getting phenotype 1
#then we just need to use our auc roc function.

roc_auc=metrics.roc_auc_score(dfphenotypes, dfpredicted)

fpr, tpr, thresholds=metrics.roc_curve(dfphenotypes, dfpredicted)

# Plot ROC curve
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, '--', label=classifierNames[i]+' (area = %0.3f)'  % roc_auc)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')  # random predictions curve
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0,     1.0])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate or (1 - Specifity)')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate or (Sensitivity)')
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(30,40))
print("auc =", roc_auc)
```